# What are the major differences between mysql5.6 and mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me the difference between mysql5.6 and mysql5.7

Answer (score 11):

The release notes for MySQL 5.7 are [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/).

"What's new in MySQL 5.7" can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html).

Changes of note:

- [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is now turned on by default, meaning MySQL
  will no longer return random data when a user has incorrectly
  specified columns in the `where` clause, but missed them out of the
  `group by` clause.
- Improvements to online DDL - more `ALTER` operations can be done
  online without the storage engine having to make a copy of the object
  in question.
- InnoDB now supports MySQL-supported spatial data types
- InnoDB [supports tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-tablespace.html)
- Native [JSON support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)
- A new [`sys` schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html), with summarized performance data
- [Multi-source replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html)